# UPDATE gridview WHERE row is selected

Tags: vb.net, gridview, sql-update

Windows form, visual basic - I have two forms; form1 is where the gridview (read only) is laid out, you can select a row and click "change status" in a menu strip. A new form will show to update the information on the selected row and a submit button to update the changes. I passed the value of the selected row on the first form to the second form.

form 1

```
Dim update As New ChangeStatus
     update.UpdatePass = InventoryGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex
     update.Show()
```

form 2

```
Public Property UpdatePass As Integer
```

(I have all the db connection set up and everything)

```
Dim cb As String = "UPDATE BMK SET RMA_Number = '" & RMAnumTxt.Text & "' WHERE ID = '" & UpdatePass
```

I need the Update string to recognize that I want to update the information on the row that is selected on the first form. But ID is always a different number considering records can be added and deleted. How can I get the UPDATE string to recognize the selected row from the gridview? I think my issue is what to put in the WHERE condition. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Gah! The sql injection vulnerability, it burns us.

Comment: I think I'm missing the problem. Is `ID` not the primary key in the database? If that is what is passed to form 2 then why doesn't it work (other than the syntax error in your sql)?

Comment: @Crowcoder Right that's what I'm asking myself as well...